# How to post an Android Studio .AAR file to a local Artifactory repository

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 to build a self-contained library (no external dependencies). Let's call it "myLib.aar".

I've been asked to modify my Gradle build to push the .AAR file into the company's private, local Artifactory repository. I am an experienced developer but know very little about Java repositories.

There are a lot of search hits on this topic, but none of them have so far resulted in a solution for my particular situation. Even more troubling, I can't find any two posts that implement a solution the same way.

I'm further confused why one can't just use an/the Artifactory plugin. Apparently one must ALSO use a Maven plugin -- but why? Some use third-party Maven plugins, some use something which appears to be built into Android Studio.

So my question is simply what lines to add to which Gradle files in order to push my .AAR file into Artifactory?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should use Artifactory plugin.
2. Re Maven plugin. The role of Maven plugin is to generate metadata about your package (the `pom.xml` file). Other option is using Ivy plugin to generate the metadata in an alternative format (the `ivy.xml` file). One way or another your package needs metadata. Select one of them (by applying `maven`, `maven-publish`, `ivy`, or `ivy-publish` plugin).
3. [The instructions about Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) show configuration examples for all the possible options.
4. [JFrog GitHub repo](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples) contains project examples for all the possible options.

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the links!  It's unclear, to me anyway, which keywords go in the top-level build.gradle file and which go in the ".\library\build.gradle" file.  Also, the .AAR example uses both "jcenter()" and "mavenLocal()" -- how do you know when to use which one?  The example also has the word 'sourceJar' in several places, but I'm building an '.aar' file so that seems confusing.  Lastly, is one supposed to use that third-party Maven plug-in or the one that's built into Android Studio?

Comment: I'm getting closer.  I'm down to the following error and am pretty sure once I get past it, all will be good.  Below is the output from running gradlew artifactoryPublish.  As you can see, there's something weird with the URL where it puts the name of my project in the path twice.  Not sure why it's doing that, how to correct it, or if it's what's causing the socket write error.

Comment: [buildinfo] Not using buildInfo properties file for this build.
:library:generatePomFileForAarPublication
:library:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://artifactory.cgaming.local/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/cgtglobal/cgdv/cgdvAndroid/cgdvAndroid/0.0.1/cgdvAndroid-0.0.1.aar
:library:artifactoryPublish FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:artifactoryPublish'.
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error